# Pass redux actions as props using Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, enzyme

How should I pass redux actions to a component using props in Enzyme tests?

This is what I have right now and it seems it's not working correctly.

```
import Flag from "./Flag";
import FlagImage from "./FlagImage";
import * as actions from "../../actions/auth";

test("Flag changes the language after click", () => {
  const flag = shallow(<Flag authActions={actions} />);

  flag.find(".flag2").simulate("click");
  flag
    .findWhere(FlagImage => !FlagImage.prop("big") && FlagImage.prop("name") === "DE")
    .parent()
    .simulate("click");

  expect(flag.state().open).toEqual(false);
  expect(flag.find(FlagImage).prop("name")).toEqual("DE") ;
```

the second expect() returns US, which is the default value, so the action doesn't get fired. The first expect() passes though, meaning that the flag has been in fact clicked.

Comment: Redux actions would normally be "connected" in `mapDispatchToProps` in the redux `connect` decorator, or used internally via redux hooks. Hard to tell if your issue is related to redux at all. What have you done in the way of debugging? Does the shallow mount actually render `FlagImage`? I suspect it doesn't. Try `console.log(flag.debug())` to see what the wrapper actually has.

Comment: using `console.log(flag.debug())` doesn't log anything at all... About rendering the FlagImage, I'm not really sure, but this is the way it is done in the docs.

Comment: It's silly, but console logs appear to be asynchronous when testing, so the output sometimes doesn't display if the test finishes before the output is flushed to the screen. In these cases I do 3-5 duplicate console logs so maybe one of them is displayed. The shallow mount does not render children, so it depends on your `Flags` component structure.